# create new html pages in phonegap app

Tags: html, cordova, mobile

I'm trying to develop an app with phonegap.
In this app i need to create dinamically (with js) other .html pages, to navigate into.

Is this possible?
I know there is a FileWriter API in phonegap, but could it create .html pages in the www folder of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create pages in the www folder at run time. Since its a packaged app and there is no knowledge of the www folder to the apk.
But if you want to create a file, use the file writer API and then it can be accessed like a normal system file.

```
window.location.href = 'file:\\myfilepath.html'
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The www folder of the application is not writable. You can create html files on the file system and navigate to them.

Comment: Oh, ok, but if I create a html file with the api method, what is the url i need to use in the <a> element?

Comment: You would use a normal file uri.

Answer (score 0):

If the pages are something you want to navigate to without persisting, you can dynamically create the elements using jQuery and insert them into the DOM.